# Как последовательно исполнить асинхронный код

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Нужно собрать массив из данных, которые можно получить ajax запросом, при этом последовательность важна.

Не знаю как реализовать это **не рекурсивно**. Данных много, а я не хочу занимать много памяти.

Если перебирать массивом, данные могут собраться в неправильном порядке, потому что никто не гарантирует в каком порядке будут получены ответы от свервера, а соответственно и выполнены коллбэки.

Как мне последовательно исполнить асинхронный код?

Вот пример кода, демонстрирующий задачу

```
function getPhotos(token, callback, errorCallback) {
    requestData = {
        access_token: token,
        count: 1000,
        offset: 0,
        photo_sizes: 1
    };

    callVK('fave.getPhotos', requestData, function(responseData) {
        if(responseData.error) {
            errorCallback();
            return;
        }

        var response = responseData.response;
        var totalItems = response[0];
        var dataArray = response.slice(1);

        //здесь, если dataArray.length < totalItems, нужно выполнять
        //callVK('fave.getPhotos', requestData, callback) несколько раз,
        // пока dataArray не наполнится до количества totalItems
    })

}
```

Comment: "Как мне последовательно исполнить асинхронный код?" - как мне белым цветом нарисовать черный квадрат? У Вас все намешано - асинхронность, рекурсия, много памяти. Попробуйте простыми словами объяснить, чего Вы хотите.

Comment: Разве пример кода не разъясняет суть задачи? Мне нужно составить массив данных. Это задача функции `getPhotos`. Сервер ограничивает количество фото, которые может выдать за раз (1000 фото). Что бы получить 2 тысячи фото, нужно сделать 2 запроса, в первом параметр offset будет 0, а в втором 1000. Мой вопрос в том, как по порядку сделать несколько запросов и сложить ответы сервера в массив. В том порядке, в котором были сделаны запросы. В синхронном языке, достаточно было бы цикла последовательно производящего запросы и сохраняющего результаты. Как быть с JS?

Comment: Хорошо. Объясните, пожалуйста, чем Вас не устраивают повторные вызовы `callVK` из колбэка.

Comment: Выделением большого колличества памяти. Внутри функции, начинает выполняться другая функция, а первая ожидает её завершения и не может освободить выделенную память. В это время, та самая (вторая) функция начинает выпонять внутри себя ещё одну функцию и все это рекурсивно, пока не выполнится последняя

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите писать асинхронный код синхронно, то посмотрите в сторону `Promise` и `async/await`.

Есть еще [предложение](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) об асинхронных генераторах/итераторах

```
// как бы это выглядело
for await (const line of asyncFoo()) {
  console.log(line);
}
```

Попробовать все это, пока что можно только вместе с [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-async-generators/)

Answer (score 0):

> Выделением большого колличества памяти. Внутри функции, начинает
>   выполняться другая функция, а первая ожидает её завершения ...

Вы ошибаетесь. Цепочные вызовы асинхронной функции не являются рекурсией в том смысле, который Вы имеете в виду. То есть call-stack не будет содержать вложенные вызовы функции. Не говоря уже о том, что память под полученные данные Вам придется выделить в любом случае.

*Update*

Смысл фразы "скиньте пруфлинк" от меня ускользает. Видимо, я не знаком с этим "новоязом". Тем не менее, добавляю маленький пример, демонстрирующий порядок действий в случае асинхронной функции обратного вызова - функция `test` не будет ждать выполнения обработчика `complete`:

```js
function test() {
  console.log("test before $.get");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://google.com', 
    complete: function(){
      console.log("from callback");
    }
  });
  console.log("test after $.get");
}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*P.S.*

По поводу: "это полная чушь". Я очень сожалею, что Вам приходится тратить время на чтение чуши. Просто не обращайте внимания на мой ответ, если он Вас не устраивает или огорчает.

Comment: Полученные данные, в примере с синхронным языком, хранит переменная. Новые данные просто добавляются в переменную. А в случае с рекурсией, чем больше уровень вложенности, тем больше выделяется памяти. Уровень вложенности 10 - 10ти кратное выделение памяти, 100 - 100кратное. Посмотрите не этот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/u5298r1k/2/ - здесь функция `test` не будет завершена до тех пор, пока не вычислится `$.get`, только после этого память будет освобождена. А теперь представьте что внутри `$.get` выполняется ещё какая-то функция, пока она выполняется, `$.get` ждёт её завершения, а вместе с ней

Comment: Вместе с ней и `test`. Если вы намекаете на то, что функция test не будет ждать выполнения `$.get`, то мне не понятно как это должно работать, лучше скиньте пруфлинк.

Comment: "Не говоря уже о том, что память под полученные данные Вам придется выделить в любом случае." - это полная чушь. Представьте что нам нужно сделать тысячу запросов. Если речь о цикле - вы всегда будете занимать 1 единицу памяти, каждая новая итерация исполняет только одну функцию, которая и занимает одну единицу памяти. В случае с рекурсией, будет занято от 1 до 1000 единиц памяти, в зависимости от текущей глубины рекурсии. 1000 единиц - на пике глубины. Надеюсь теперь вам более понятно что я имел в виду

Comment: @TryCatch 1) Где вы тут увидели рекурсию? 2) Рекурсии бывают разные. То, чего вы так боитесь - это хвостовая рекурсия, которая тут не применима(если не упарываться)

Comment: Тот пример который вы привели, доказывает только то, что `test after $.get` срабатывает раньше чем `from callback`. И никак не опровергает то, что во время выполнения `$.get`, `test` не освобождает память. А на счёт ваших сожалений, продолжайте сожалеть о чем угодно - это не доказывает вашего утверждения. Если вы заинтересованы в аргументации - попробуйте сослаться на стандарт, описывающий это поведение. Так было бы намного более конструктивно